# MySql docker container, via terminal works, via docker-compose no

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

the following file is a docker-compose file. If I execute it via docker-compose up the container create itselfs but is impossible to connect to server, via terminal as via database visual editor. And, if I check the container via docker inspect by terminal, some vaule (i.e. IPaddress) are empty.

If I try to create the same container but manually via docker run command, passing the same parameters via command line, all works perfectly and if I check the container via docker inspect via terminal, all values are correct (also, in particular, IP address) and I can connect to the database so via terminal as via db visual editor.

Why it happens, and why in particular creating the mySql  container via this docker-compose file the ipaddress seems empty? Is my docker compose file not correct? I checked several times with

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=xyz
    ports:
    - 127.0.0.1:port_number:port_number
    volumes:
    - mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    - ./mysql-init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    command:
    - --max-allowed-packet=64M

volumes:
  mysql: {}
```

EDIT: to reply to 2 users,

1) Port_number was exactly 3306 in the orginal file;
2) The full run command is

```
sudo docker run --name my_mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my_password -p 3306:3306 mysql:5.7
```

Comment: Please include the full `docker run` command you use.

Comment: just add  `ports: 3306:3306`

Comment: I replied to both users by editing my original question. Thank you very much!

Comment: Is the Compose container actually starting up; a couple of the options are different?  The `docker inspect` output is pretty low-level debugging information that isn't usually useful, and in particular the IP address it reports doesn't work in many extremely common contexts.

Comment: Thank you very much David; the inspect is not foundamental, is only to report you an additional information. The main problem is that, via docker compose it doesn't work and via command line it works correctly. Have you an idea?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is the issue is you're listening on IP 127.0.0.1, which is local to the container and therefore can't be accessed remotely. You should listen on 0.0.0.0.

Long version: https://pythonspeed.com/articles/docker-connection-refused/

Comment: The stock `mysql` image correctly binds to 0.0.0.0; you don't need special configuration for this.

Comment: Your theory is correct but I don't think is the solution. Othercases, how were possible that creating the same container by command line; testing this container by sudo docker inspect; checking in the terminal that the IP address is exactly 127.0.0.1 and testing the connection of this one by mysql visual editor extern to the container all works? Thank you very much everycase for your reply, have you other idea?